# How to intercept data being transferred between computer USB and device

Tags: dll, usb, .so

I need to implement a Android driver for some USB devices that currently only have .dll and .so x64 libraries. Unfortunately, there is no documentation of exactly what bytes I should send on the write endpoint.

So if I could intercept the byte array parameters being transferred by the .dll libraries I could put this parameters into my Android driver implementation.

Is there a way to read everything being write to a USB by a .dll or .so library?

Note: I found some answers on SO on how to intercept call made TO a .dll. What I need is to see the bytes send FROM the .dll to the USB device.

Answer (score 0):

I found a software called [USBlizer](http://www.usblyzer.com/monitor-usb-traffic-analyze-usb-device-activity.htm) that can capture all data sent and received by the USB similar to what devtools on browsers do for HTTP requests, including the data and the program making the request on the column and panel "Raw Data".